# Saving mongodb Id in any key as string vs saving as ObjectId

Tags: mongodb

I wanted to know if there is any performance gain or loss in case I save any existing mongoId as string in any other document key. For example I have two collection ans i am saving one collection document Id i.e is _id to another document key as string . I am not going to use it as ref but it is for Viewing purpose and later i can use it to fetch  the information from another collection. Example
One doc

```
         {_id : ObjectId() , Name : "Test"} // This is one document
```

Second doc in another collection

```
        {_id : ObjectId , Detail : { AID : ObjectIdASString } } // ObjectIdAsString is Id from first document
```

Comment: There's not a big difference, but the string is larger and I don't see a reason why you would store the referenced id as string, but the id itself as objectid. Why don't you store both as `ObjectId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store it as `ObjectId`, `ObjectIds` require less space on disk. Plus, it would be easier and more efficient to sort your collection based on `ObjectId` rather than strings. However, nothing scary about it, you can easily convert `ObjectId` to string and vice versa using `toString()` and `valueOf()` methods respectively.